# Annotating chord voices in Lilypond

Tags: lilypond

Is it possible to achieve something like this in Lilypond? I've been wondering for years, but now I'm trying to do some work that makes this more pressing.

[chord examples from Schillinger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbqRM.png)

Thank you so much!

I've tried various standard text methods, and searched the documentation and elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Balloon Text is the way to go in Lilypond!

This is how I ended up doing it:

```
\new Staff \with {
    \consists Balloon_engraver
    \override BalloonText.annotation-balloon = ##f
    \override BalloonText.annotation-line = ##f
    \override Clef.space-alist.first-note = #'(minimum-fixed-space . 10.0)
}
{
    \relative c' {
        \balloonLengthOn
        \override Score.SpacingSpanner.spacing-increment = #3
        \override BalloonText.layer = #-2
        \override Staff.StaffSymbol.layer = #-3
        \override BalloonText.whiteout = ##t
        <
        e-\balloonText #'(0.1 . 0) \markup{"3"}
        -\balloonText #'(-1.5 . 0) \markup{"b"}
        g-\balloonText #'(1.3 . 0) \markup{"5"}
        -\balloonText #'(-0.5 . 0) \markup{"c"}
        c-\balloonText #'(0.1 . 0) \markup{"1"}
        -\balloonText #'(-1.5 . 0) \markup{"a"}
        >2
        <
        g,-\balloonText #'(0.3 . 0) \markup{"5"}
        -\balloonText #'(-0.5 . 0) \markup{"c"}
        e'-\balloonText #'(0.3 . 0) \markup{"3"} 
        -\balloonText #'(-0.5 . 0) \markup{"b"}
        c'-\balloonText #'(0.3 . 0) \markup{"1"} 
        -\balloonText #'(-0.5 . 0) \markup{"a"}
        >
    }
}
```

and it produced [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LiuO.png)